# Top Counts...return tuple format of output back to dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, count, tuples, words

I need the top 10 words and their count, already contained in a dictionary, in the following format:

word count (e.g.   hello 10)

I have the following code:

```
for word in word:
            if word not in counts:
                     counts[word] = 1
            else:
                    counts[word] += 1

for word in counts:
            top = sorted(counts.items())
            top_10 = top[:9]
print top
```

the output is a list with tuples inside:  [('red', 5), ('blue', 2), ('green', 1), ...]

However, I need it in the format of :

red 5

blue 2

green 1

How can this be done???

Comment: can you place your wordlist here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
print top
```

with

```
for k,v in top: print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can count with less (and more pythonic) code:

```
for word in words:
    count[word] = count.get(word,0) + 1
```

Second, you can achieve the printing format you want with:

```
for k in count:
    print k,count[k]
```

If sorting is your problem you can use `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
words = ['brown','yellow','red','blue','green','blue','green','blue','green']
count = {}
for word in words:
    count[word] = count.get(word,0) + 1


top = sorted(count.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
top_10 = top[-10:]
print top_10
```

Comment: So, if I have less than 10 words, it repeats them.  Is there a way to make it so that if there are less than 10, it returns what is present, sorted?

Comment: Here are the data from the test set:

resapi 1
egypt 1
rakuten 1
simak 1
baca 1

This is what that code is printing:

baca 1
simak 1
baca 1
resapi 1
simak 1
baca 1
resapi 1
rakuten 1
simak 1
baca 1
resapi 1
egypt 1
rakuten 1
simak 1
baca 1

Repeats of the words, and not even in the same order...why??

Comment: For what it matters, my words are not in a single list...they print in the format: [word] "\n" [next word] "\n" .....

Comment: Okay..tried it on another dataset...Now I get the top 10, but we are back to format.  They are a list of tuples!!!

Comment: dude, you stated that words are a `dictionary` - not that it's a list of tuples... anyways, glad that you figured it out.

Comment: @ alfasin  They are a dictionary.  The format of the input is complicated:  "entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Egypt","indices":[139,140]}],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Nervana_1","name":"Nervana Mahmoud","id":255040592,"id_str":"255040592","indices":[3,13]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"en"}
Now...imagine this across 5 minutes of API data collection.

Comment: @MJMV the answer Sarath wrote: `for k,v in top: print k, v` will work if `top` is a `tuple`, while the answer I wrote: `for k in count: print k,count[k]` will work when `count` is a `dictionary`. You say it's a dictionary and at the same time you say that his answer worked for you.

Comment: @alfasin...I stand corrected.  At different extractions, the data type changes.  It seems that by the time I get to the bottom, the data are now list, and your counting code creates a list containing tuples, each of which has a (word, count).  
[('resapi', 1), ('egypt', 1), ('rakuten', 1), ('simak', 1), ('baca', 1)]

Thanks for bringing this up.  It's an important part of this learning process to see what the data have become, and what snippets of code I can use on various types of data.

Comment: @MJMV NP that's fine, as long as you keep track of things and you know which data structure you're dealing with. In general, when the DS gets too "composed" I rather create an object (class) and relevant accessor methods - which makes everything clearer and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily acheive this by using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['brown','yellow','red','blue','green','blue','green','blue','green']
c=Counter(words)
for i,j in c.most_common(10):
    print i,j
```